# Web hosting and language compatibility?

Tags: web, hosting

I am trying to learn as much as I can about web applications. With all of the different languages and frameworks and hosting sites, it's very difficult to even figure out what I want to learn. I understand server side, client side, mvc, and the languages that belong to each of those. However one thing that confuses me is language compatibility. That being said, I'm going to outline some questions that I have.

1. In general, is any front end feature/framework compatible with any server side language/framework? For example, could I use AngularJS with say PhP, or Python/Django?
2. How does question 1 factor into web hosting sites? Am I able to pick a random hosting company and just start using any front end framework or backend framework I want? Or do they have to be compatible?
3. What is the best way to go about learning all of these issues I'm having with language/framework compatibility?
4. Let's say I love using jQuery, and Java servlets, and MySQL. Are those even compatible? If so would any framework for those three be comptible with each other?

I understand I am being vague, but I really need a solid starting point on all of this. I want to learn all of these awesome technologies, but I want to make sure I understand, in a general sense, what makes frameworks compatible or incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In general, is any front end feature/framework compatible with any
>      server side language/framework? For example, could I use AngularJS
>      with say PhP, or Python/Django?

Yes, you can.  (One exception to that: some rare frameworks are combined front-end and backend things.  Obviously they have to be used as a unit.  But they're rare, and easy to spot because they say that they're combined.)

> 2. How does question 1 factor into web hosting sites? Am I able to pick a
>      random hosting company and just start using any front end framework or
>      backend framework I want? Or do they have to be compatible?

You can use pretty much any front-end with any web host.  One exception: if the front-end needs to use WebSockets (unusual, I don't know of any that do, but wouldn't be surprised if one exists) then your backend host will need to support it.  Many (most?) only support regular HTTP.

Back-end language support depends on the host.  For example, my own employer (PythonAnywhere) only really supports Python (our aim is to support it better than anyone else does).  There are others only support PHP.  And so on.  Some hosts support pretty much anything, though often with those you have to do quite a lot of setup yourself.

> 3. What is the best way to go about learning all of these issues I'm
>      having with language/framework compatibility?

Build something!  Set yourself a small project, something you can put together as a learning experience and then throw away.  Try the simplest front-end/back-end combo you can find.  Then maybe try porting the front end to something else, or the backend.  Experiment, and you'll learn.

> 4. Let's say I love using jQuery, and Java servlets, and MySQL. Are those
>      even compatible? If so would any framework for those three be
>      comptible with each other?

Yes, they're all compatible.  Personally I'd avoid servlets like the plague though. Too much experience with Java before I switched to Python ten years ago...

Answer (score 0):

In general, is any front end feature/framework compatible with any server side language/framework? For example, could I use AngularJS with say PhP, or Python/Django?

> >
>    PHP is more compatible with the server side languages/frameworks. You can surely use them.

How does question 1 factor into web hosting sites? Am I able to pick a random hosting company and just start using any front end framework or backend framework I want? Or do they have to be compatible?

> >
>   There is compatibility between the backend and front end. Because many of the backend technologies are not compatible with the backend.

What is the best way to go about learning all of these issues I'm having with language/framework compatibility?

> >
>   As experience is the best teacher, you can test and try at your end. You should experiment the codes and will come to know the compatibility. There are various online articles and PDF available from which you can learn the all things easily.

Let's say I love using jQuery, and Java servlets, and MySQL. Are those even compatible? If so would any framework for those three be comptible with each other?

> >
>   Yes, there is compatibility issue. All frameworks are not compatible with each other.